# end to end testing :- Protractor error : unknown error: call function result missing 'value'

Tags: protractor, angular5, e2e-testing

here is the code in page object.

```
 getPageTitle () {
return browser.getTitle (); 
}
```

And in my script i have wrote down this code. :

```
it('Title should be Project', () => {

    page.navigateTo();
    page.getPageTitle()
      .then((title: string) => {
        expect(title).toEqual('Project');
      });
  });
```

After that, i am getting this error. I have no idea why i am having this, while my title is written properly.

```
    1) project App Title should be Project
  - Failed: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436382 (70eb799287ce4c2208441fc057053a5b07ceabac),platform=Linux 4.13.0-41-generic x86_64)

Executed 1 of 1 spec (1 FAILED) in 0.699 sec.
[11:55:50] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[11:55:50] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[11:55:50] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[11:55:50] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1

(node:26179) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! project@0.0.0 e2e: `protractor "./protractor.conf.js"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project@0.0.0 e2e script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/student-08/.npm/_logs/2018-05-23T09_55_51_005Z-debug.log

Some end-to-end tests failed, see above.
```

I also tried with this :

```
it('Title should be Project', () => {
page.navigateTo();
expect(page.getPageTitle()).toEqual('Project');
 })
```

But still having the same problem.
Any idea what have i done wrong ?

Comment: We dont have access to your `navigateTo()` or `getTitle()` functions. Could you either add these functions, or create a test case without them where you get the same error?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there is a delay for the title to load. So instead of checking for the title,  try waiting for it after `page.navigateTo()` :

```
browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.titleIs('Project'));
```